# Liberty class loading issues or problem with hibernate (migrating tomcat app on liberty)?

Tags: jpa, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

i have to deploy a multi-module application in ear on Liberty Server 20 in my Eclipse. This application use hibernate as provider jpa2 and Derby client + driver derby-10.12.1.1.jar(as shared fileset). Persistence.xml is configured with non jta.
This is server.xml:

```
<enterpriseApplication id="rubrica-ear" location="rubrica-ear.ear" name="rubrica-ear"/>
    <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/TestappDS" type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">


        <properties.derby.client createDatabase="false" databaseName=".rubrica"></properties.derby.client>
        <jdbcDriver>
            <library>
                <fileset dir="C:\programmiMio\java-eclipse\drivers" id="shared"></fileset>
            </library>
            
        </jdbcDriver>
    </dataSource>
```

My .rubrica db location is in /usr/home.
Because I dont want to start a server derby on console but automatically, i do taht in a @WebListener class:

```
@WebListener
public class ReqListener implements ServletContextListener {
    
    static final Logger log =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReqListener.class);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    private NetworkServerControl derbyserver;
    
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        try {
            String userHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home", ".");
            String systemDir = userHomeDir + "/.rubrica";
            // Set the db system directory and startup Server Derby for incoming connections.
            System.setProperty("derby.system.home", systemDir);//il db viene salvato qui

            derbyserver =   new NetworkServerControl(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 1527);
            derbyserver.start(pw);
            log.info("Apache derby settings ok");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        if (derbyserver!=null){
            ...
        }

    }
```

When i deploy i get this error

```
[ERROR] An error occurred in the org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence persistence provider when attempting to create the entity manager factory of the testapp persistence unit container. The following error occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.TypeInfo.extractTypeInfo(TypeInfo.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.createEMFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:919)
    at [internal classes]
```

When I debug on Liberty i see that Hibernate classes running before the @WebListener code (this is not the same thing in Tomcat), how can i resolve this issue? Something about class loading settings?

I try derby Embedded instead, but problem still araise again, in server.xml:

```
 <properties.derby.embedded createDatabase="create" databaseName="C:/Users/myuser/.rubrica" shutdownDatabase="false"/>
        <jdbcDriver>
            <library>
                <fileset dir="C:\programmiMio\java-eclipse\drivers" id="shared-libs"/>
            </library>
    </jdbcDriver>
```

Thanks

Roberto

Comment: You said didn't want to start derby on console but automatically, why not just use derby embedded and let Liberty control the lifecycle for you?

Comment: @FRowe i update my question, adding derby embedded but nothing change..

Comment: The `at [internal classes]` obfuscates a bit of when this is occurring, but I am going to go out on a limb and guess that this is during applicaton startup, when the JPA Runtime Integration is creating an EntityManagerFactory in order to acquire a Class Transformer that it needs to register with the application ClassLoader before application classes are loaded.
   
Some persistence providers eagerly connect to the DB during EMF creation (I believe Hibernate is one), which means the DB must be active before starting the application.  OpenJPA/Eclipselink wouldn't do this.

Comment: @FyreWyld so you suggest me to use openJpa/eclipse link for profile Websphere? So  can i use embedded websphere jpa provider without problem? i think maybe to create two maven profiles one tomcat + hibernate dep only and another was+openjpa dep only..but if so why in tomcat not happens?

Comment: if you change to use derby embedded, you wouldn't need the @WebListener to start the db server.  If you have changed to derby embedded and removed the anno and you're still getting an exception, please post it, because derby embedded db should be available by the time the EMF is being created as discussed by FyreWyld.